# Unable to decode credential from JWT

Tags: php, jwt, google-signin, google-identity

I am trying to implement the new "Sign in with Google" button as described in `https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button`.

Everything is fine, and I am able to get a response from the button with "credential" and "g_csrf_token" elements, which I can send to my server. However, using the Google API Client to decode the credential doesn't work. I'm trying to follow the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token).

Here's my code:

```
    $id_token = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'credential');
    $csrfToken = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'g_csrf_token'); //??? Do we need this?
    
    $client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $clientid]);
    $client->addScope("email"); // Recommended in another StackOverflow answer but makes no difference
    try {
        $payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
    } catch(Exception $ex) {
        $errorMessage = "Error in verifyIdToken():" . $ex->getMessage();
        // ...do stuff with the error message
    }
    // ...do stuff with the returned payload
```

The result is the error message `id_token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken`.

I've updated my Google API Client to v2.11.

I assume that I've missed a step somewhere - can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Have found a solution, by trial and error! Turns out that `$id_token` needs to be passed to the client twice, once in `setAccessToken()` and then again in `verifyIdToken()`. Omitting `setAccessToken` fails (like the error message says), but if you pass it in `setAccessToken` but NOT in `verifyIdToken`, that doesn't work either.

```
$id_token = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'credential');
$client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $clientid]);
try {
    $client->setAccessToken($id_token);
    $payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
} catch(Exception $ex) {
    $errorMessage = "Error in verifyIdToken():" . $ex->getMessage();
    // ...do stuff with the error message
}
// ...do stuff with the returned payload
```

It would nice, if you're at Google and picking this up, if you updated the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
$client = new Google_Client([**'client_id'** => $clientid]);
```

**'client_id'** must be your google client id from https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/

you need to register your web app in google cloud